# Passing Post request through postman for has_many association in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby, postman

I am a new learner and need some help. I have two models (which I generated through scaffold). Category and Product.

```
  class Category
   include Mongoid::Document
   field :name, type: String

   has_many :products
   accepts_nested_attributes_for :products
 end

 class Product
   include Mongoid::Document
   include Mongoid::Paperclip
   include Mongoid::Timestamps::Created

   field :name, type: String
   field :description, type: String
   field :prize ,type: Integer
   field :category_id
   field :user_id

has_mongoid_attached_file :avatar,
  :styles => {
      :thumb => "150x150#",
      :small  => "150x150>",
      :medium => "550x550#{}" }

belongs_to :user
belongs_to :category
end
```

My Category controller

# POST /categories.json

```
 def create
    @category = Category.new(category_params)


    respond_to do |format|
      if @category.save
        format.html { redirect_to @category, notice: 'Category was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @category }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @category.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end

    end


 def category_params
      params.require(:category).permit(:name,product_attributes: [ :name, :description,:prize ,:category_id])
    end

  end
```

My json format

```
{

    "name":"Mens Clothing",
    "products_attributes": [
        {

            "name":"Denim jeans",
            "Description": "test test test"
            "prize":1000,
            "user_id":1,
        }
    ]
}
```

Now my question is when I am trying to hit localhost:3000/categories through postman the values are not getting saved. Also I don't know whether my json format is correct or not or either my categories controller code is correct. I am new and trying to figure out how the data is saved in json format for has_many relation in rails.iam getting missing params error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have the base resource name as a key in your JSON:

```
{"category": {

    "name":"Mens Clothing",
    "products_attributes": [
        {

            "name":"Denim jeans",
            "Description": "test test test", # <== Added a comma here
            "prize":1000,
            "user_id":1,
        }
    ]
}}
```

`params.require(:category)` indicates you want to look at the incoming parameters and pull the value of the `:category` key, raising an `ActionController::ParameterMissing` exception if that key is not found.

If the `:category` key is found, its value is passed to `#permit`, which filters out any keys that are not included in the approved list.

Because you didn't have `:category` in your params, your logs should reflect an `ActionController::ParameterMissing` exception.

Comment: thank you #moveson .but Iam still getting this error.ActionController::ParameterMissing (param is missing or the value is empty: category):

Comment: Please edit your question to show the full server logs starting from "started POST /categories" and ending with "Completed xxx in xxxms".

Comment: thanks man, problem is solved actually i was trying to fetch data from postman .and on changing some changes to controller create actions i got what i wanted .your answer gave me a road-map to solution.